# Expression Engine plugin to allow {embed} code in entry body

Tags: embed, expressionengine

Trying to create a generic video plugin for Expression Engine 2 where I can put the {embed:video_plugin file_name='FILE'} within the entry article body and have it then load the plugin.

We are able to have this work on one template using the HTMLPurifier module, but that strips out too much code like script, style and other tags we still want to allow.

Does anyone know of a plugin or way to allow this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allows EE code to be placed in your entries then parsed by the template:
http://expressionengine.com/downloads/details/allow_ee_code/

Various video players:
http://devot-ee.com/search/results/search&keywords=video%20player&channel=addons&addon_version_support=ee2

Alternative solution:
I usually create a field (Matrix) that contains all my images and videos, I can then output these on a per entry basis.

Using NSM Transplant or the free MX Jumper, I can then replace any specific {embed} within a lump of text with my video.  Here's an example:

```
{exp:mx_jumper:out_global}
    {images}
        {exp:mx_jumper:put name="image-{row_count}"}
            <a href="{image}" rel="prettyPhoto" class="{if "{alignment}" == ""}right{if:else}{alignment}{/if}">
                {exp:ce_img:single src="{image}" alt="{alt-text}" width="690" crop="no" bg_color="FFF"}
            </a>
        {/exp:mx_jumper:put}
    {/images}
    {content-text}
{/exp:mx_jumper:out_global}
```

This example outputs images from a matrix field (called images), but the same principle can be used for video.  In my Wygwam textfield, called {content-text}, I add {image-1}, {image-2}, etc within the text to position the item.

Whatever EE code or even html code you use to display the video can be placed into the {exp:mx_jumper:put} tag pair, using video paths pulled from the entry.

You could replace Matrix for a simple textfield which just contained the path.

Comment: This ended up working like a charm for me: http://expressionengine.com/downloads/details/allow_ee_code/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like we may have some term overlap going on here.

Typically when using the word embed it's used in reference to embedding a template within another template. I don't think this is what you'r trying to do.

Anything wrapped within the HTML Purifier plugin will be sanitized (assuming nothing crazy is going on with parse order). I would recommend dedicating an entire field to the video content, rather then try to include it with other content in one field.

There are several plugins / field types that will be helpful to you.

1) http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/antenna
Antenna is a plugin that grabs data about a YouTube or Vimeo video and format it in a standard way.

2) http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/channel-videos
Channel Videos is a field type / module that allows you to search Vimeo and YouTube directly from the entry edit screen and then include selected videos in a template.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I meant it the way you initially thought. I want to be able to embed something in a template. I just need to insert the code inside an entry's article body. Thing is HTML Purifier seems to make this work on one of our pages, but it does not do so well with many of our other pages where we have script, style and other tags we do not want stripped out. We have our own player and stream content on our site, thus the video plugin I'm writing to be able to send the filename and possibly playlist to it.